# When saving ggplotGrob directly in R, it works, but when running this save within R markdown knit, x-axis labels are missing

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I implemented the solution of this thread: [Adjust discrete y-axis height to number of segments in facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223156/adjust-discrete-y-axis-height-to-number-of-segments-in-facets)

```
# Make labels even
plt.grid <- plt + facet_grid(Soort ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")
plt.wrap <- plt + facet_wrap(. ~ Soort, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")

gp.grid <- ggplotGrob(plt.grid)
gp.wrap <- ggplotGrob(plt.wrap)

gp.wrap$heights[gp.wrap$layout[grep("panel", gp.wrap$layout$name), "t"]] <- 
  gp.grid$heights[gp.grid$layout[grep("panel", gp.grid$layout$name), "t"]]

plt <- ggdraw(gp.wrap)

# Save
ggsave('_temp20.png',plt,device='png',width = 19.8, height = 10, unit = "cm")
```

When I run this within the .R file, it looks perfect. However, when this piece of code is ran from a RMarkdown knit, the x-axis labels are missing. Does anyone know of this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I patched together the pieces of code the original poster, the original answer and your provided code (changing `Soort` by `organism_name`). When put in an .R file and sourced, it gives me a plot with x-axis labels. When put into an .Rmd file and knitted, it also gives me a plot with x-axis labels.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I don't understand why this is happening... Did you also leave in the ggsave part?

Comment: Yes I did and also printed the plot regularly in the .Rmd file to cover both options.