# how to group levels of each subgroup in a forest plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

```
> dput(fig2b_data)
structure(list(subgroup = c("sex", "sex", "ai_comorbid_bool", 
"ai_comorbid_bool", "non_ai_comorbid_bool", "non_ai_comorbid_bool", 
"age_70_plus", "age_70_plus", "ecog_combined", "ecog_combined", 
"indication_combined", "indication_combined", "site", "site", 
"site", "site", "site", "site", "site", "site"), level = c("Female", 
"Male", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "0", "1+", "Adjuvant", 
"Metastatic / Unresectable", "Cambridge", "Belfast", "Cardiff", 
"Liverpool", "Norwich", "Preston", "Southampton", "Taunton"), 
    subgroup_level = c("sex_Female", "sex_Male", "ai_comorbid_bool_No", 
    "ai_comorbid_bool_Yes", "non_ai_comorbid_bool_No", "non_ai_comorbid_bool_Yes", 
    "age_70_plus_No", "age_70_plus_Yes", "ecog_combined_0", "ecog_combined_1+", 
    "indication_combined_Adjuvant", "indication_combined_Metastatic / Unresectable", 
    "site_Cambridge", "site_Belfast", "site_Cardiff", "site_Liverpool", 
    "site_Norwich", "site_Preston", "site_Southampton", "site_Taunton"
    ), ref = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), adj_or = c(1, 1.92697788983048, 1, 
    0.309313271153888, 1, 1.60176654927755, 1, 0.581067651194834, 
    1, 0.606677244239784, 1, 0.757510322046024, 1, 0.0671548910659019, 
    1.24115412701041, 0.111740502056371, 0.296334401152569, 0.407313416513578, 
    0.100703132319318, 0.0580853387590806), ci_low = c(NA, 1.08574689964253, 
    NA, 0.0933004210866726, NA, 0.813446935851162, NA, 0.300096568750007, 
    NA, 0.301300997438692, NA, 0.395638695943013, NA, 0.0184879397812241, 
    0.316512222510664, 0.0310182213975059, 0.0774035454553755, 
    0.0834303368267395, 0.0228743220824828, 0.011193138928203
    ), ci_high = c(NA, 3.4667621174982, NA, 0.929482385449043, 
    NA, 3.1938659749789, NA, 1.11325241104074, NA, 1.21374279615277, 
    NA, 1.44670881667103, NA, 0.205952672316014, 4.59055508109202, 
    0.342443550375257, 1.00710088916867, 2.04034216674928, 0.387728614421501, 
    0.257636420370032), p = c(NA, 0.0263295963311719, NA, 0.0432646112707497, 
    NA, 0.175314541854903, NA, 0.103298047943536, NA, 0.158264479732785, 
    NA, 0.399589361570504, NA, 8.78601713425597e-06, 0.747238599523183, 
    0.000291277241946869, 0.0597081504970594, 0.260985385401162, 
    0.00132018341690714, 0.000328378914869459), sig = c(NA, TRUE, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), col = c("REF", 
    "UP", "REF", "DOWN", "REF", "INSIG", "REF", "INSIG", "REF", 
    "INSIG", "REF", "INSIG", "REF", "DOWN", "INSIG", "DOWN", 
    "INSIG", "INSIG", "DOWN", "DOWN")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to draw a forest plot, but where each level is grouped by subgroup. How can I do this?

I've tried this so far to get my plot, but struggling with grouping the levels:

........................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
# plot
ggplot(data = fig2b_data, aes(x = adj_or, y = subgroup_level)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = ci_high, xmin = ci_low, color = col), size = .5, height = .2) +
  geom_point(aes(color = col), size = 2) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: forest plot]

I would like:

```
_________________________
Sex
Male (ref)                        x
Female          |----x-----| 
_______________________________________________________________
AI comorbid
No (ref)                          x
Yes          |----x-----| 
_______________________________________________________________
Site
Cambridge(ref)                    x
Preston          |----x-----| 
Southampton                     |----x-----| 
Belfast                                        |----x-----|

__________________________________1____________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was quite of a workaround. The adjusted hight for the `facet_wrap()` height is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223156/adjust-discrete-y-axis-height-to-number-of-segments-in-facets)

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

fig2b_data_cleared <- fig2b_data %>%
  mutate(subgroup = fct_recode(subgroup, "Age >= 70" = "age_70_plus",
                                         "AI Comorbidities" = "ai_comorbid_bool",
                                         "ECOG" = "ecog_combined",
                                         "Indication" = "indication_combined",
                                         "Non-AI Comorbidities" = "non_ai_comorbid_bool",
                                         "Sex" = "sex",
                                         "Site" = "site"),
         subgroup_level = fct_relevel(subgroup_level,  "age_70_plus_Yes", "age_70_plus_No",
                                      "ai_comorbid_bool_Yes", "ai_comorbid_bool_No",
                                      "ecog_combined_1+", "ecog_combined_0", 
                                      "indication_combined_Metastatic / Unresectable", "indication_combined_Adjuvant",
                                      "non_ai_comorbid_bool_Yes", "non_ai_comorbid_bool_No",
                                      "sex_Male", "sex_Female",
                                      "site_Belfast", 
                                      "site_Cardiff", "site_Liverpool",
                                      "site_Norwich", "site_Preston",
                                      "site_Southampton", "site_Taunton",
                                      "site_Cambridge"))


p <- ggplot(data = fig2b_data_cleared, aes(x = adj_or, y = subgroup_level)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = 2, color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(color = col), size = 3) +
  xlab("Adjusted Odds Ratio") +
  ylab("") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmax = ci_high, xmin = ci_low, color = col), size = 0.8, width = 0.5) + 
  theme(plot.title.x = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = 180, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=c("age_70_plus_No", "age_70_plus_Yes",
                            "ai_comorbid_bool_No", "ai_comorbid_bool_Yes",
                            "ecog_combined_0", "ecog_combined_1+",
                            "indication_combined_Adjuvant", "indication_combined_Metastatic / Unresectable",
                            "non_ai_comorbid_bool_No", "non_ai_comorbid_bool_Yes",
                            "sex_Female", "sex_Male",
                            "site_Cambridge", "site_Belfast",
                            "site_Cardiff", "site_Liverpool",
                            "site_Norwich", "site_Preston",
                            "site_Southampton", "site_Taunton"),
                   labels=c("No (Ref)", "Yes",
                            "No (Ref)", "Yes",
                            "No (Ref)", "Yes",
                            "No (Ref)", "Yes",
                            "No (Ref)", "Yes",
                            "Female (Ref)", "Male",
                            "Cambridge (Ref)", "Belfast", 
                            "Cardiff", "Liverpool",
                            "Norwich", "Preston",
                            "Southampton", "Tanton")) +
  scale_color_discrete(limits = c("REF", "INSIG", "DOWN", "UP"),
                       name = "")

p.grid <- p + facet_grid(subgroup ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")
p.wrap <- p + facet_wrap(~ subgroup, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")

gp.grid <- ggplotGrob(p.grid)
gp.wrap <- ggplotGrob(p.wrap)

gp.wrap$heights[gp.wrap$layout[grep("panel", gp.wrap$layout$name), "t"]] <- 
gp.grid$heights[gp.grid$layout[grep("panel", gp.grid$layout$name), "t"]]

grid::grid.draw(gp.wrap)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: That’s brilliant! Thanks. How do I get the Subgroup names and their respective levels in a table on the left (where to subgroup name is in bold and the level names are indented)?

Comment: how to you save output of `grid::grid.draw(gp.wrap)` to a variable?

Comment: There are ways to force ggplot to do so, like using `geom_text` and `clip = "off"`. However, this would tike quite an amount of time. A simpler option would be to put the gray boxes to the left: `p + facet_grid(subgroup ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = "y")`, however, since your strip labels are quite long, they get cut off.